# Do somebody knows how to create something like that in discord.py?

Tags: button, menu, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to create discord bot with all new features. Today I saw this and i can't find out how to do that.

[image: I need to create something like that]

Comment: I do not think that this is possible right now as this just came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## These are Message Commands. This feature will be released in discord.py 2.0

discord.py 2.0 is the next major version of discord.py is currently in development. You can track the development [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/projects/3) 
[message commands in the discord API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands)

### Alternatives

- VoxelBotUtils ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/voxelbotutils/)) VoxelBotUtils (VBU) is an extension for Discord.py to speed up Discord bot development. It includes a whole slew of features that are commonly used in a lot of bots so you don't need to keep writing them every time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is in the current version of discord.py. However, there is beta versions of discord.py that maybe has these features, you'll have to join the discord server and get the beta tester role (which is public). the link is here:

**https://discord.gg/dpy**